# Ultrasound iphone (Shopkick signal technology)

Tags: iphone, detection, frequency

I think shopkick is detecting very high frequency signal which is not audible to human ear.But the real question is how they can detect signal of more than 22khz in iphone. I have checked frequency response of iphone mic,it seems to be from 20 hz to 22 khz within the human audible range.

http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2009/iphone/iphone-microphone-frequency-response-comparison/ http://www.businessinsider.com/shopkick-crate-barrel-2010-12?op=1

Can you guide me on this. If it is possible with iphone mic,then we can able do some signal processing specifically FFT in order to get frequency.

Comment: Most adults can not hear much above 15 - 16 kHz so perhaps they are just using the top end of the range, e.g. 18 - 19 kHz ? It would be interesting to see if kids or dogs can hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am currently working on a similar system of transmitting data using these high frequencies and this is what I found out. Al-thou keep in mind that I am doing this with Android phones, mostly Galaxy S line. 
First of all spectrum of 20khz to 22khz seems quite promising because it can be detected by all phones we tested and even reproduced by some of them. These frequencies are inaudible to humans of any age and even the dogs and cats seem to not notice them. If you are targeting (actually avoiding) detection by humans you could even go to as low as 18khz since most people wouldn't hear that. This gives you a bandwidth of 4000hz which you can Frequency modulate a data into. Of course don't expect to transmit 8mp images but some small data can be transmitted. You are right in the part that you could than use FFT to transit into frequency domain and analyse those frequencies, this can be done even on older phones in Java (I think doing it in objective c would be even faster).

Also if you have few iPhones on your disposal you could install any frequency analyser and play the frequencies you want on another iPhone or some speaker to test what they can detect. Just keep in mind that standard desktop speakers would probably be able to play the given frequencies but will introduce noise of lower frequency. Piezo tweeters are probably best for these type of sounds al-thou I must say I am using iPhone 4 to play these frequencies for testing quete efficiently.

I read somewhere that Shopkick now even plays there sound codes over stores PA-s and since those speakers are not really optimised for above 20khz response I too am starting to suspect they are using frequencies below that.  Take a look at this website for different store codes that some people are using to cheat the system http://www.ceploitips.com/2011/03/shopkick-walk-in-files.html
Keep in mind that using these might ban your account since they improved there misuse detection algorithms.

Also I too would like to read more about the Shopkick implementation so if anyone viewing this has some link please share.

Comment: Hey @PSIXO this is coming pretty late, but do you suspect that laptops also can get close to the range you put above (18-22khz)?

Comment: @NickPineda In most cases yes. Many integrated speakers in laptops are able to reproduce these frequencies. I tried this on few Lenovo, Dell and MacBook devices and it worked. But there are unfortunately no guaranties that it will work on all and that might be a problem depending on your use case. Actually my theory is that the reason why apps using this kind of communication are most prevalent for iPhone is the fact that basically every iPhone has the same hardware and if it works on one it will work on all of them.

Comment: Unfortunately there is much less guarantee about this for laptops and android devices, although Google did release support for this for android http://android-developers.blogspot.rs/2015/07/connect-with-world-around-you-through.html

Answer (score 1):

First, human hearing pretty much tops out at 20 KHz and even that requires a very young human and a very low and erratic shift along those upper frequencies. For example, I can produce a tone as low as 18 KHz at full iPad volume at a sample rate of 48 KHz that even my dog doesn't notice. Read up on PsychoAcoustics and you will see that humans filter echoes at even very low frequencies that are there but we don't notice them.

But in the case of ShopKick, I don't think they are going above even 21 KHz. I have created several digital audio modulations on the iPhone and 21 KHz seems to be the upper limit for any distance at all.

It would help if you gave more input on what you are doing. I assume from the question you want to modulate a digital signal between two devices.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that they are using maximal length sequences. These are almost like a weak background hiss that covers a large range of the audio spectrum. The key to detection is that the pattern repeats exactly and the phone has a key that detects the sound by correlating the key and the incoming audio.